# Error en el registro PHP

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Hola buenas noches espero que estéis bien os comento quiero hacer uso de este código

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Registro</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
//Registro Web para contas PRODEV - Elysium Engine Brasil 2.6, por Lucas Lôpo
$user=$_GET['nome'];    //Esta parte cria as variáveis com os dados que foram inseridos no formulário.
$password1=$_GET['senha1'];
$password2=$_GET['senha2'];
$mail=$_GET['email'];
if($password1==$password2) //Comprova que as senhas são iguais.
{
$teste=file_exists("C:\Binários\Servidor\Contas\\".$user.".ini"); //Comprova que a conta não existe.
    if($teste==1)
    {
        echo "Nome de usuario em uso.";
    }
    else
    {
        $arquivo=fopen("C:\Binários\Servidor\Contas\\".$user.".ini","a+"); //Verifica que a conta existe , e então muda o diretorio para o correto.
        fwrite($arquivo,"[GENERAL]");   //Adiciona ao conteudo do Arquivo.
        fwrite($arquivo,chr(13).chr(10));
        fwrite($arquivo,"Login=".$user);
        fwrite($arquivo,chr(13).chr(10));
        fwrite($arquivo,"Password=".$password1);
        
        echo "Você acaba de criar sua conta.";
    }
}
else
{
    echo 'As senhas não conhecidem.<br>';
    echo '<a href=index.html>Voltar</a>';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Y me gustaría que creará otro archivo en diferente carpeta solo con el nombre del usuario.

Lo he intentado mil veces pero no tengo manera siempre me da error en el ELSE.

Comment: Hola, cual es el error que te indica?, a simple vista veo que te falta cerrar el documento fclose($archivo);

Comment: No es un error el código que mande funciona perfectamente. Pero me gustaria que esta linea $arquivo=fopen("C:\Binários\Servidor\Contas\\".$user.".ini","a+"); //Verifica que a conta existe , e então muda o diretorio para o correto. Me dejara crear un nuevo archivo. Es decir el Archivo me lo crea pero necesito que me cree otro con el nombre de usuario.

Comment: Entiendo que intentas crear un archivo de no existir, pero tu pregunta no es tan clara, comentas que intentas cosas pero no muestras lo que realizaste, Probaste fopen("C:\Binários\Servidor\Contas\\".$user.".ini","w+b")?

Comment: No se entiende demasiado bien lo que quieres.  ¿Ese nuevo archivo que quieres ubicar en otro sitio y que solo tiene que tener el nombre de usuario (entiendo que sin extension) que contendra?  ¿Es un archivo vacio?  ¿Contendra lo mismo que el actual con `.ini`?

Comment: tiene toda la pinta de que esto este mal: `C:\Binários\Servidor\Contas\\ ` ya que te faltarian dobles barras en algunos sitios. Quizas te funcione mejor con `C:\\Binários\\Servidor\\Contas\\`

Comment: El código repito esta bien es un registro en la cual cuando rellenas el formulario de registro crea un archivo y se va a la carpeta que pongas. Lo que quiero hacer es añadir una linea en para que el nombre de ususario cree un nuevo archivo y se diriga en una carpeta especificada

Comment: Pues duplica ese código que ya funciona con el nuevo nombre y la nueva ruta, no?

Comment: Si solo duplico el $arquivo=fopen("C:\Binários\Servidor\Contas\\".$user.".ini","a+"); //Verifica que a conta existe , e então muda o diretorio para o correto. para otra carpeta no me crea el archivo solo me crea 1

Comment: Si alguien tiene tiempo y me lo puede explicar en vivo mucho mejor ya que seria de gran ayuda también me podría explicar mucho mejor https://discord.gg/7aKFBAVu Soy borrachosmallorca

Comment: A ver, vamos por partes porque me estas liando :-)   Dime el nombre del nuevo archivo y la ruta final que quieres poner y que quieres que contenga ese archivo.  Por ejemplo, algo asi como "C:\Binários\Servidor\OtraCarpeta\usuario" y lo que quieres que contenga... es decir, ¿lo quieres solo creado o con contenido?  Los problemas los resolvemos aqui, no en discord.

Answer (score 0):

Tal como has especificado en los comentarios, lo que quieres podria ser esto:

Sustituye esto:

```php
$arquivo=fopen("C:\Binários\Servidor\Contas\\".$user.".ini","a+"); //Verifica que a conta existe , e então muda o diretorio para o correto.
fwrite($arquivo,"[GENERAL]");   //Adiciona ao conteudo do Arquivo.
fwrite($arquivo,chr(13).chr(10));
fwrite($arquivo,"Login=".$user);
fwrite($arquivo,chr(13).chr(10));
fwrite($arquivo,"Password=".$password1);
```

Por esto:

```php
// primer archivo
$arquivo=fopen("C:\Binários\Servidor\Contas\\".$user.".ini","a+");
fwrite($arquivo,"[GENERAL]\n");
fwrite($arquivo,chr(13).chr(10)."\n");
fwrite($arquivo,"Login=".$user."\n");
fwrite($arquivo,chr(13).chr(10)."\n");
fwrite($arquivo,"Password=".$password1."\n");
fclose($arquivo);

// segundo archivo
$arquivo=fopen("C:\Binários\Servidor\Carpeta2\\".$user,"a+");
fwrite($arquivo,"[GENERAL]"."\n");
fwrite($arquivo,chr(13).chr(10)."\n");
fwrite($arquivo,"Login=".$user."\n");
fwrite($arquivo,chr(13).chr(10)."\n");
fwrite($arquivo,"Password=".$password1."\n");
fclose($arquivo);
```

Si el `$user` es, por ejemplo, **Pedro**, este código te creará los archivos siguientes con el mismo contenido:

```
C:\Binários\Servidor\Contas\Pedro.ini
C:\Binários\Servidor\Carpeta2\Pedro
```

Fijate que simplemente he duplicado el código existente cambiando la ruta y la extensión del archivo. Y también he agregado `fclose($arquivo);` porque cuando abres un puntero al sistema de archivos con `fopen`, luego hay que cerrarlo con `fclose`.

He puesto el mismo contenido en ambos, pues no has dicho ni si ni no a lo que quieres que contenga.

Ahora es cosa tuya elegir la ruta y modificar la extensión del segundo archivo si no te gusta así, y tambien su contenido si quieres agregar o eliminar cosas.

Comment: masterguru mil gracias tal cual me lo dijiste funciona perfectamente! Pero ahora tengo otro problema me crea el archivo todo seguido mesclado. Se podria poner en esta parte: $arquivo=fopen("C:\Users\Ismael\Desktop\PROJECTO 2019\Servidor Oficial\accounts\\".$user.".ini","a+");
fwrite($arquivo,"[GENERAL]");
fwrite($arquivo,chr(13).chr(10));
fwrite($arquivo,"Login=".$user);
fwrite($arquivo,chr(13).chr(10));
fwrite($arquivo,"Password=".$password1);

Comment: fwrite($arquivo,"QueteSW= 0");
fwrite($arquivo,"QueteC=0");
fwrite($arquivo,"Sex= 0");
fwrite($arquivo,"Sprite=19");
fwrite($arquivo,"Level= 1");
fwrite($arquivo,"Exp= 0");
fwrite($arquivo,"STR= 5");
fwrite($arquivo,"DEF= 5");
fwrite($arquivo,"Exptotal= 0"); que sea cada cosa abajo de otra? y no una linea toda seguida como me esta creando?

Comment: Me alegro :-)  Recuerda aceptar la respuesta para que no quede pendiente eternamente si ha respondido correctamente a tu pregunta. Puedes aprender como aceptar respuestas aqui:  https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200

Comment: Prueba poniendo `\n` al final de cada texto entrecomillado, por ejemplo: `fwrite($arquivo,"QueteSW= 0\n");`

Comment: si aun me queda la ultima duda para que se ponga todo linea es decir

Comment: Ahora si cierro hilo mil millones de gracias

Comment: Acabo de agregar el salto de linea en la respuesta, mira a ver si ahora te sirve... si hay mas de los debidos los quitas tu mismo.

Comment: ¿Ya lo has conseguido?  ¿Esta todo bien ahora?  Si es así no hace falta que me lo agradezcas más, con tantos miles de millones de agradecimientos no hago demasiada cosa :-)  La forma de "agradecer" algo en este sitio es aceptando las respuestas si son correctas. Mírate [ask], haz el [tour] y [como aceptar respuestas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) y así aprenderas mejor como funcionamos aqui y la proxima vez tendras más ayuda de más gente.